# Loop through dates in knockout and create group of dates by month

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of random dates that I am generating on the server and sending back in json format to a knockout viewmodel into an observableArray() ([01/02/2016, 01/15/2016, 02/04/2016, 03/05/2016, etc..)  and can't quite wrap my head around how to iterate over those dates and to create the following output in html:

```
January
-------
01/02/2016
01/15/2016

February
-------
02/04/2016

March
-------
03/05/2016
```

etc...

I understand basic foreach loops in knockout, and dynamically outputting html and all that. Would the best course of action be to create an observable array for each month, and then in html only show the month section if that month's observable array's length is > 0?

```
var januaryArray = ko.observableArray();
var februaryArray = ko.observableArray();

<ul id="januaryList" data-bind="foreach: januaryArray, visible: januaryArray.length > 0">


    .....

<ul id="februaryList" data-bind="foreach: februaryArray, visible: februaryArray.length > 0">
.....
```

Or is there a better, more succinct way to accomplish this with some if statements?

Comment: could you just filter your original array for each month. using ko.utils.arrayFilter http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment user2744722. I scoured the internet for 2 days looking for a solution to this, and of course minutes after posting this question I came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163547/group-events-by-date-using-knockoutjs

I'm going to work on a solution later tonight, and if this helps solve my issue I will post it so maybe it can help others!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one I did using the ko.utils.arrayfilter

here is the fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/othkss9s/27/

here is the javascript.

```
function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.dates = ['01/02/2016', '01/15/2016', '02/04/2016', '03/05/2016'];

  this.months = ko.observableArray([{
    name: 'January',
    value: '01'
  }, {
    name: 'February',
    value: '02'
  }, {
    name: 'March',
    value: '03'
  }]);

  this.filteredDates = function(data) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.dates, function(item) {
      return item.substr(0, 2) === data.value;
    });
  };
}

var myViewModel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(myViewModel);

});
```

here is the html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: months">
  <li>
    <b data-bind="text: $data.name"></b>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $root.filteredDates($data)">
      <li>
        <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```